# Multi-call - Route calls to multiple cell phones at once

Tags: applications

I have 2 employees, each with their own cell phone and cell number. I am trying to find some service where I can call one number and both of these employees' cell phones ring; the one who picks up first takes the call. Ideally this would happen by calling either of the employees' existing lines, but having it happen when someone called a new, 3rd line would also work. I only need this for 2 employees.

I know Google Voice can do this, but unfortunately their VoIP service has had too many issues with lag/choppiness for me to use them for business. Do you know any other apps, services, or otherwise that can do this without sacrificing call quality?

Thanks!